# How to create multiple data frame from one data frame with multiple condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset, multiple-columns

I would like to create `four` data sets from the following given data frame by multiple conditions in `x1` and `x2`

```
mydata=structure(list(y = c(-3, 24, 4, 5, 3, -3, -3, 24, 5, 4, 8, 7, 
                            9, 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 8, 12, 9, 10, 12, 11, 2), 
                      x1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                             0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
                            ), 
                      x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                             0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA,25L))
```

The first data set is `mydata00` which is constructed with these conditions `x1=0` and `x2=0`,

```
mydata00=filter(mydata, c(mydata$x1==0 & mydata$x2==0))
> mydata00
   y x1 x2
1 -3  0  0
2 -3  0  0
3  8  0  0
4  3  0  0
5  9  0  0
```

Now, I need only the `unique` values of `y` and corresponding `x1` and `x2`. Finally, I would like to sort `y`. So my final data set must look like

```
   y  x1 x2

1 -3  0  0
2  3  0  0
3  8  0  0
4  9  0  0
```

I would like to do the job for `mydata11`, `mydata10`, `mydata01`, where ,

```
mydata11=filter(mydata, c(mydata$x1==1 & mydata$x2==1))
mydata10=filter(mydata, c(mydata$x1==1 & mydata$x2==0))
mydata01=filter(mydata, c(mydata$x1==0 & mydata$x2==1))
```

Can I use any for loop or builtin functionn to create these data sets?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the data based on unique values of `x1` and `x2` and get `unique` rows in each list after ordering it by `y`.

```
temp <- lapply(split(mydata, list(mydata$x1, mydata$x2)), function(x) 
                     unique(x[order(x$y), ]))
temp

#$`0.0`
#    y x1 x2
#6  -3  0  0
#18  3  0  0
#16  8  0  0
#21  9  0  0

#$`1.0`
#    y x1 x2
#14  2  1  0
#5   3  1  0
#10  4  1  0
#4   5  1  0
#...
```

If we need data as a separate dataframe, we can name them appropriately and use `list2env`.

```
names(temp) <- paste0("mydata", names(temp))
list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

`tidyverse` way of doing this would be :

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% group_split(x1, x2) %>% map(~.x %>% arrange(y) %>% distinct)
```

Comment: It is not giving the sorted version. I need to sort the `y` values.

Comment: Updated the answer to sort it by `y` values.